# map invoke failed: JS Error: Error: fast_emit takes 2 args (anon):1

Tags: mongodb

A collection will be created from the below js file , i need three Fields in my collection so i have given

```
 emit(this.cust_id, 1,date);
```

Its giving the below Error

map invoke failed: JS Error: Error: fast_emit takes 2 args (anon):1

But its working fine with `emit(this.cust_id, 1);`

Please tell me ow to include date aslo in the collection created ??

```
m = function() { 
 var currentDate = new Date();
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()-1);
        var month = (currentDate.getMonth() < 9 ? "0"+ (currentDate.getMonth()+1) : (currentDate.getMonth()+1));
        var day = (currentDate.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getDate() : currentDate.getDate());
        var date = currentDate.getTime();
emit(this.cust_id, 1,date);
 }

r = function (k, vals) { var sum = 0; for (var i in vals) { sum += vals[i]; } return sum; }

   q = function() {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()-1);
        var month = (currentDate.getMonth() < 9 ? "0"+ (currentDate.getMonth()+1) : (currentDate.getMonth()+1));
        var day = (currentDate.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getDate() : currentDate.getDate());
        var date = currentDate.getTime();
        var patt = date;
        var query = {"created_at":"2013-30-04 11:19:52.587"};
        return query;
}


res = db.logins.mapReduce(m, r, { query : q(), out :  "LoginCount" });
```

Comment: btw, I don't understand the point of your q() function - it just returns a simple { created_at: fixed date } and all the other operations are not used anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you can only emit two arguments.  One represents the key over which you will be grouping/aggregating values and the other represents the value for this document.

If you need to calculate multiple fields you need to output a single value which is a document.   In your example if 1 represents count and date represents some date you can output:

```
emit(this.cust_id, {count: 1, date: this.date);
```

This is if you are pulling the date from the document.  I'm not sure why you would want to store the date when map was running, but obviously you can include your own date in that field.

Note that when you emit value as a document you must return the exact same format in your reduce function.  You can see an example of that [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/#calculate-order-and-total-quantity-with-average-quantity-per-item), where they output two different values for each emit and then process both in reduce (you can ignore the finalize function).

Comment: Thanks for the help , but i got the output as { "_id" : "testuser", "value" : 2 }  , i want to include Date Field also .

Comment: I dont want to include the date in emit , but i want in my output collection . This is my requirement .

Comment: what date should be in the output collection?  One that represents "now()"?  If so then emit key, count pairs and add a finalize function which creates another field in the value that includes the date.  But if you want the same date in all the records why can't you first run your map/reduce and then update all the records adding the same date to them with one update statement?

Comment: is this basically a duplicate of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322178/mongodb-mapreduce-out-collection-result ?

Comment: So you mean to say that i can keep the emit function as it is emit(this.cust_id, 1); and add a finalize function to include date field in the collection ??

Comment: Yes i want the Date field , that represents "now().

Comment: Ca you please tell me how to add a field using finalize ??

Comment: look at the finalize function in the linked example.  Just add another field to value - like value.date = <DATE>; return value - but this requires having the value be an object, not a simple number.

Comment: Are you trying to see per day per user how many logins there are?  Is that the ultimate goal?

Comment: Ya , that is my my requirement , per User how many logins and also i want to include a Date Field